# Can't create new DB in RavenDB 2.x

Tags: ravendb

Noob RavenDB question:  Just brought down Raven 2.x and set it up to run in IIS.  Just trying to create a new DB in RavenDB 2.x through the Studio.  I have the following set in my configuration:

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>
```

I have the physical location set to allow Everyone full control.  When I try to create a new database, I get the following:

Could not get authorization for this command.
If you should have access to this operation contact your admin and check the Raven/AnonymousAccess or the Windows Authentication settings in RavenDB

### Server Error:

### The operation '/admin/databases/Test' is only available to administrators

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this value to be:

```
  <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/>
```

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on this option.  Can you briefly explain what this setting does?  Why wouldn't "All" work in this case as well?  Thanks!