# RavenDb - Unable to create Database. Error:- Unauthorized Unauthorized

Tags: ravendb

I am getting following error when i hosted the file in IIS7.

> Could not get authorization for this command. If you should have
>   access to this operation contact your admin and check the
>   Raven/AnonymousAccess or the Windows Authentication settings in
>   RavenDB
>   I had my configuration as follows:-

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>
```

Which i changed to below after i googled to find some solution. I [one of the posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060800/cant-create-new-db-in-ravendb-2-x) by Ayende Rahien he mentioned to change it as below(which i did ) :-

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/>
```

But now i am getting error as:-

> Requested value 'Admin' was not found.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Admin'
>   was not found.

I have seen previous posts similar to my issue as [Unable to create databases when running RavenDB on IISExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876983/unable-to-create-databases-when-running-ravendb-on-iisexpress) and also [Can't create new DB in RavenDB 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060800/cant-create-new-db-in-ravendb-2-x)

What am i doing wrong?

My web.config configuration  is as follows:-

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="Raven/Port" value="801"/>
        <add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Database\System"/>
        <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/>  
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have windows authentication enabled in IIS, so it can actually log you in.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. What a fool I am. It works after Enabling Windows Authentication.